# Thymeleaf get object from select-tag and show attributs in another select-tag

Tags: java, spring-boot, thymeleaf

Here is a little code example:

```
<select name="widgetType">
<option th:each="widgetType : ${session.widgetTypeList}" th:value="${widgetType}" th:text="${#strings.capitalize(widgetType.name)}"></option>
```

```
<select name="widgetSize">
<option th:each="widgetSize : ${widgetType.widgetSizeList}" th:value="widgetSize.id" th:text="${widgetSize.id}"></option>
```

I want to show a selection with different widgetSizes based on the widgetType the user selected first.
But this example is not working.

How i have to do this?

Comment: I want to be clear: `<select name="widgetType"><option ...></option>` is working but `<select name="widgetSize"><option ...></option>` is not?

Comment: Yes, the widgetType selection is working fine. But when i select one type, the widgetSize selection is always empty. The question is, if themyleaf can access the value from widgetType direct? Because i have not implementet any logic behind the second selection.

Comment: Try to change `th:value="widgetSize.id"` to `th:value="${widgetSize.id}"`

Comment: Ok, i changed this, but the second selection is still empty. I think that widgetType of the second selection is null